# modify a variable of a struct instance

Tags: c

```
struct test{

    int value;
    struct test *child;
};


void change(struct test *t){

    t->child[1].value = 100000;
    t->child[0].value = 100000;
} 

int main (void) {

    struct test *f = (struct test *)malloc(sizeof(struct test));
    struct test *s = (struct test *)malloc(sizeof(struct test));
    struct test *t = (struct test *)malloc(sizeof(struct test));
    struct test *list = (struct test *)malloc(2*sizeof(struct test));

    f->value = 1;
    s->value = 1;
    t->value = 1;
    list[0] = *s;
    list[1] = *t;
    f->child = list;
    //init(t);was a typo
    change(f)
    printf("%d",t->value);

}
```

How can I change the value of t->value to 100000 without changing the struct and the param? I was trying to create a new instance of the struct in change() but still not working.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Which line isn't working as expected?

Comment: I hope the result is 10000 but it gives me 1

Comment: `list[1] = *t;` This makes a **copy** of the struct where `t` points to. If you modify the copy, that does not affect `t` or `*t`.

Comment: Assuming your original code calls `change` instead of `init`, you pass a pointer to a struct, where there is no memory allocated for `child` member. Accessing `->child[0]` is illegal.

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a typo. So should I make a deep copy? and change the value of the copy then assign it to t->child[1]?

Comment: What would you gain by a deep copy? `t->child` is not initialized. Nothing to copy yet. You should probably use a pointer instead of a copy.

Comment: You should check whether `child` is allocated before attempting to write to it; it means first assigning `NULL` to `->child` as soon as **any** `(struct test *)` is allocated. Then think that you have really allocated 5 objects through `malloc()`; is it what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code (might be unrelated to your question): 

 
1. The "init" function is not defined, I assume this should be "change" instead. 

 
2. If you call change(t), you are accessing uninitialized pointer in change, and the behaviour of your program would be undefined, so I assume that instead of

```
f->child = list
```

you meant:

```
t->child = list
```

3. I guess you wanted to not use step 2 as I mentioned above, rather you wanted to somehow make the program write something in f, with a size longer than f, so that the program overflows and starts writing on the next memory locations and so "without changing the struct and param" as you mentioned, the value of t is changed. 
   If this is the case (I hope I am getting the question write), then you overlooked the fact that calling malloc consecutively does not guarantee allocating consecutive chunks of memory, I ran your code and the following is the addresses allocated to pointers:

```
sizeof struct: 8
addresses : f: b72f18 , s: b72f48 , t: b72f80 , list: b72f90
```

All of this answer should have been posted in a comment, but comments are not yet unlocked for me.

Comment: It looks like the address of ' t->child[0] ' and ' s ' are different. So is it possible that I can make ' t->child[0] ' points to the same memory address with ' s '

Comment: The problem here is that t->child is not assigned any memory. it is just a dangling pointer. You have to first do something like t->child = (struct test *) malloc(2 * sizeof(struct test)), only then you are allowed to assign variables to t->child[0] and t->child[1], otherwise you are accessing illegal parts of your memory.

Comment: I'm trying to print the ' t-> value ' in main function. In change(), I passed ' f ' and the child of ' f ' was initialized in main function.